# .grofile .accounts_facebook?

Tags: css, wordpress, blogs

I am trying to learn more about wordpress designing and I downloaded a templete (easiest way for me to play around and learn) & in one of the script files I noticed

```
.grofile .accounts_facebook {background-position: 0px -0px;}
```

With more social media names and types. I tried to google it, however nothing came up. Does anyone know exactly what this is? Should I be putting it on my websites or just blogs?

Comment: whats the reason u tagged java?

Comment: it was in a javascript file, I didn't realize I tagged java, I thought it auto completed javascript. Sorry